# Бот-модератор телеграм на PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет, коллеги.
Решил написать бота-модератора для группы в Телеграме на php.

Чтобы он для начала удалял сообщения со стоп-словами.

Бота создал, все первоначальные действия, типа загрузки на хостинг и установку вебхука выполнил, в группу добавил, запустил, админом сделал.

Как теперь его программировать, чтобы он следил за сообщениями в группе. Группа, кстати, разделена на темы

До этого писал ботов, но не модераторов.

Спасибо..)

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? В боте получаете все сообщения из группы. Анализируете текст каждого сообщения. Если в нем есть стоп слова, то удаляете это сообщение.

Comment: Посмотрел ваши вопросы,.. без ответов) Поймите, вам на такое никто не ответит.. как минимум потому что нужно видеть ваш код, знать чего вы хотите и что у вас не получилось... Вангую тут тоже не ответят. Найдите лучше учителя)

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как боту получать, перехватывать и обрабатывать сообщения участников, публикуемые в группе ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держи пример, можешь дописать в ответе на вебхук отправку сообщения что сообщение удалено и т.п.

Но до полноценного и нормального бота надо много чего дописывать, и использовать лучше библиотеки, а не как тут с голыми запросам

```
<?php

// Задаем токен бота
$bot_token = '12345678:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

// Задаем список стоп-слов
$stop_words = array('слово1', 'слово2', 'слово3');

// Проверяем, получено ли сообщение с помощью вебхука
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
  // Получаем объект сообщения
  $message = json_decode($_POST['message']);

  // Проверяем, есть ли стоп-слово в сообщении
  foreach ($stop_words as $word) {
    if (strpos($message->text, $word) !== false) {
      // Удаляем сообщение со стоп-словом
      file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $bot_token . '/deleteMessage?chat_id=' . $message->chat->id . '&message_id=' . $message->message_id);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: О, спасибо огромное! Буду пробовать!